# pre_get_posts shows posts in random order sometimes

Tags: order, pre-get-posts

I'm using the following filter in order to increase the amount of posts shown on category templates from 10 to 30 (I want to keep 10 for the rest of the site)

```
// Modify number of results shown
function modify_query_amount_shown($query){
    if ($query->is_category) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 30);
        $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_amount_shown');
```

However, when I refresh my page several times, I notice the order of my posts changes each time. I can confirm that it has something to do with this code, because as soon as I comment it out, it returns to normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre_get_posts` is not a filter hook, it is an action. Also you should not set `orderby` to `menu_order` for posts as they are not hierarchical. Set `orderby` to `date` instead.

```
function modify_query_amount_shown( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 30 );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_amount_shown' );
```

Now the order of posts displayed will be consistent, regardless of the number of refreshes.

Comment: Thank you! How silly...by the way I was able to remove the orderby completely and it still works as intended.